# Is there a possibility that a warning message comes up with a note if

Tags: magento2

Is there a possibility that a warning message comes up with a note if someone enters their postcode or city when paying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to display a warning message or note in Magento when someone enters their postcode or city during the payment process. You can achieve this by customizing the checkout form, adding JavaScript validation, and modifying the relevant template and JavaScript files.